# New Relic for local .NET application

Tags: .net, newrelic

I'm new to [New Relic](http://www.newrelic.com/) and tried to add the functionality to my .NET WebApi application. When I run my project from Visual Studio I cant connect to it from New Relic. Offcourse I use IIS Express to debug my application. But i don't understand if its possible to test and use New Relic when debugging my application in IIS Express?

What i already tried is using the IIS and test it on another project. That works, but not in IIS Express.

New Relic keeps saying: Waiting for data...

Comment: I doubt your question has enough details for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try what the docs recommended? https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/new-relic-browser/troubleshooting-page-view-monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: When added my project to IIS locale i can now use New Relic.

Comment: Can you say more specific steps how to do that ? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Hi, yes i follow these steps: Open IIS Manager -> Add your project folder as a new site -> Run it and you can access it by the browser -> Don't forget to open ports for New Relic: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/site/networks